# How to save h264 frames as jpeg images using ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, jpeg, h.264

I would like to save thumbnails from a h264 stream that I'm turning into ffmpeg avpackets as jpegs.

I'm started with a h264 AVPacket (iframe) and decode it into an AVFrame using avcodec_send_packet/avcodec_receive_frame. Now trying to go from AVFrame and convert into AVPacket using avcodec_send_frame/avcodec_receive_packet

I can convert to png instead jpg, though I do get a the video looking like it's outputting three separate frames squeezed side by side into one. Wondering if it's one frame is R, next G, and finally B. I'm not sure, clearly I'm doing something wrong there. I figured it's possible it's the png encoder and I don't need it, so let's get jpg working first. But jpg is outputting unopenable files.

Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
int output_thumbnails(AVPacket* video_packet)
{
    char png_file_name[max_chars_per_filename];
    char thumbnail_id_char[10];
    _itoa_s(thumbnail_id, thumbnail_id_char, 10);
    strcpy_s(png_file_name, max_chars_per_filename, time_stamped_filepath);
    strcat_s(png_file_name, max_chars_per_filename, time_stamped_filename);
    strcat_s(png_file_name, max_chars_per_filename, thumbnail_id_char);
    strcat_s(png_file_name, max_chars_per_filename, ".jpg");
    thumbnail_id++;

    int error_code = send_AVPacket_to_videocard(video_packet, av_codec_context_RTSP);

    //if (error_code == AVERROR_EOF)
    //{
    //  //  error_code = videocard_to_PNG(png_file_name, av_codec_context_RTSP, av_codec_RTSP);
    //}
    if (error_code == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) //send packets to videocard until function returns EAGAIN
    {
        error_code = videocard_to_PNG(png_file_name, av_codec_context_RTSP);

        //EAGAIN means that the video card buffer is ready to have the png pulled off of it
        if (error_code == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            //  error_code = videocard_to_PNG(png_file_name, av_codec_context_RTSP, av_codec_RTSP);
        }
        else if (error_code == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            deal_with_av_errors(error_code, __LINE__, __FILE__);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        deal_with_av_errors(error_code, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

VideoThumbnailGenerator.h:
#include "VideoThumbnailGenerator.h"

```
bool decoder_context_created = false;
bool encoder_context_created = false;

AVCodecContext* h264_decoder_codec_ctx;
AVCodecContext* thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx;

int send_AVPacket_to_videocard(AVPacket* packet, AVCodecContext* codec_ctx)
{
    if(!decoder_context_created)
    {
        AVCodec* h264_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_ctx->codec_id);
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(h264_codec);

        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->width = codec_ctx->width;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->height = codec_ctx->height;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->skip_frame = AVDISCARD_NONINTRA;//AVDISCARD_NONREF;//AVDISCARD_NONINTRA;
        
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 30;

        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->extradata = codec_ctx->extradata;
        h264_decoder_codec_ctx->extradata_size = codec_ctx->extradata_size;
        
        int error_code = avcodec_open2(h264_decoder_codec_ctx, h264_codec, NULL);
        if (!h264_codec) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (error_code < 0)
        {
            return error_code;
        }
        decoder_context_created = true;
    }

    
    //use hardware decoding to decode video frame
    int error_code = avcodec_send_packet(h264_decoder_codec_ctx, packet);
    if(error_code == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    {
        return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    }
    if(error_code<0)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not send packet to video card");
        return error_code;
    }

    return 0;
}

int videocard_to_PNG(char *png_file_path, AVCodecContext* codec_ctx)
{
    if (!encoder_context_created)
    {
        //AVCodec* thumbnail_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PNG);
        AVCodec* thumbnail_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_JPEG2000);
        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(thumbnail_codec);

        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->width = 128;
        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->height = (int)(((float)codec_ctx->height/(float)codec_ctx->width) * 128);
        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24; //AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P
        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
        thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 30;

        bool thread_check = thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->thread_type & FF_THREAD_FRAME;
        bool frame_threads_check = thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx->codec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_FRAME_THREADS;
        
        int error_code = avcodec_open2(thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx, thumbnail_codec, NULL);
        if (!thumbnail_codec) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (error_code < 0)
        {
            return error_code;
        }
        encoder_context_created = true;
    }
    
    AVFrame* thumbnail_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket* thumbnail_packet = av_packet_alloc();
    //av_init_packet(png_packet);
    int error_code = avcodec_receive_frame(h264_decoder_codec_ctx, thumbnail_frame);

    //check for errors everytime
    //note EAGAIN errors won't get here since they won't get past while
    if (error_code < 0 && error_code != AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    {
        printf("Error: Could not get frame from video card");
        return error_code;
    }
    //empty buffer if there are any more frames to pull (there shouldn't be)
    //while(error_code != AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    //{
    //  //check for errors everytime
    //  //note EAGAIN errors won't get here since they won't get past while
    //  if (error_code < 0)
    //  {
    //      printf("Error: Could not get frame from video card");
    //      return error_code;
    //  }
    //  
    //  error_code = avcodec_receive_frame(h264_decoder_codec_ctx, png_frame);
    //}

    //now we convert back to AVPacket, this time one holding PNG info, so we can store to file
    error_code = avcodec_send_frame(thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx, thumbnail_frame);

    if (error_code >= 0) {
        error_code = avcodec_receive_packet(thumbnail_encoder_codec_ctx, thumbnail_packet);

        FILE* out_PNG;

        errno_t err = fopen_s(&out_PNG, png_file_path, "wb");
        if (err == 0) {
            fwrite(thumbnail_packet->data, thumbnail_packet->size, 1, out_PNG);
        }
        fclose(out_PNG);

    }
    return error_code;
}
```

Comment: That's a worrying level of `strcat` in allegedly C++ code. Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Probably a good idea to switch over to string, just read a little bit about strcat performance problems. I tend to stick to C functions and C++ only as needed but that seems like a good one. Thanks.

Comment: It's not performance problems, it's eliminating the fuss of using fixed-sized buffers and risking a buffer overflow or memory leak.

Comment: Using strcat_s which should help on buffer overflow/memory leak front. Fixed sized buffer removal.. would be nice for this program performance comes first though.Thanks tadman.  At the moment more worried about getting this jpg saved to the file correctly though.